# Infinite Scroll Wordpress Causing "Read More" Error

Tags: wordpress, scroll, infinite

I'm using the Infinite Scroll Wordpress plugin and for some reason, the "Continue Reading" link is not showing correctly for all posts that are loaded using the plugin. Here is a link: http://fieldtreasuredesigns.com/. Once you scroll down far enough for more posts to load, you should notice that the "Continue Reading" link messes up. What's happening is that the actual text, "Continue Reading" is being pushed outside of the  and it's just showing up as text instead of inside the link. Why does it do this?

Here's the html for a properly formatted "Continue Reading" link:

```
<div class="entry-content">
                                    <p>Ok friends, let&#8217;s face it. It&#8217;s always time for coffee around here. So this week I am doing a giveaway to help you have a solid coffee time as well. It&#8217;s super easy to enter to win. Just repost the photo above on @Instagram with a shout to @fieldtreausuredesignsa and use the hashtag #fieldtreasurecoffeetimegiveaway. If </p>
                <a class="more-link auto" href=http://fieldtreasuredesigns.com/field-treasure-coffee-time-giveaway/>Continue reading &raquo;</a>                                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

And here's an example of what happens to the "Continue Reading" link for a post that was loaded when someone scrolls down to the end of the page and the Infinite Scroll plugin loads more:

```
<div class="entry-content">
                                    <p>Yesterday I shared a live periscope&nbsp;of a little behind the scenes of our temporary shop and the last Saw Horse Desk build process for 2015. Enjoy! (Click the little play button down at the bottom if the video doesn’t automatically load.)</p>
                <a class="more-link auto" href="http://fieldtreasuredesigns.com/periscope-sawhorsedesk-bth"></a>Continue reading »                                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You text outside the anchor tag that's its happen please check archive page to fix it.

**Fixed code**

```
<div class="entry-content">
                                    <p>Yesterday I shared a live periscope&nbsp;of a little behind the scenes of our temporary shop and the last Saw Horse Desk build process for 2015. Enjoy! (Click the little play button down at the bottom if the video doesn’t automatically load.)</p>
                <a class="more-link auto" href="http://fieldtreasuredesigns.com/periscope-sawhorsedesk-bth">Continue reading » </a><div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @VasimVanzara - I still don't understand where on archive.php the edit should be made. Here is a link to my archive.php file: http://txt.do/ddpcm